# Alignment in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align some content in Bootstrap 4. It's not working the way I think and I don't understand why. Specifically, I'm unable to vertically or horizontally align content in a column. For example, in this [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/mHsRs6imq9), I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <h2 class="display-4">Some Text</h2>
    <p class="lead">
      Some other details go here. This portion can go up to three lines of text. It will wrap around to the next line. A YouTube video will be available in the right side.
      It's not there because Bootply doesn't allow iframes.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4">
    <div style="border:solid 2px #ddd;">
        A vertically centered YouTube video.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="font-size:3.0rem;"></div>                                    
          </div>

          <div class="col-9">
            <h3 class="card-title">Detail</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Here's some more info for you. This could go up to three lines of text. How do I center the arrow?</p>                                            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I vertically align the YouTube video so that it's centered? How do I vertically align the arrow so that it's centered? I can't seem to even get the arrow to center horizontally. I tried using `justify-content-center` as mentioned [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) without any luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested flexbox

```
.col-3 {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
  }
```

[**Bootply**](https://www.bootply.com/iiuKUhvGwR)

Comment: Why isn't the arrow centered horizontally though?